# Is a dynamic Vue instance a good practice?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a general question about Vue handling. I am currently working on a website with a registration. At the same time I have assigned roles to the users (1. Customer, 2. Admin).
After login the admin is redirected to the admin dashboard. The admin dashboard is a Vue SPA. I implemented the customer backend with Livewire.

When I am in the backend as a customer, Vue should not load. I don't have an #app tag there either. That's why I get the console error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Cannot find element.
```

Which is also correct.

Now my question.Is it a good practice to query in my app.js if #app is present in the DOM and if not, then no Vue instance is initiated.
Is it a good practice to query in my app.js if #app is present in the DOM and if not, then no Vue instance is initiated.
Here is my app.js with the condition:

```
// app.js
require('./bootstrap');
require('alpinejs');

import Vue from 'vue
import router from './router/router';
import csrf from './apis/csrf'; require('alpinejs')
Vue.use(router)

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

// Check if #app in DOM
if (document.getElementById('app') !== null) {
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        router
    });
}
```

Comment: No. If it's known that an app isn't supposed to be instantiated, the script just doesn't need to be loaded, it wastes bandwidth otherwise.

Comment: I understand! A can handle this in the Blade Template. Thanks Estus